# Web Worker - Is it possible to subscribe / catch the init function from inside the Worker js?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web, web-worker

When creating new Worker instance with a name, for example:

```
// index.js
const myWorker = new Worker('./worker.js', { name: 'myWorker' });
```

Is it possible to subscribe/catch the initialization from inside `worker.js` and then, for example, grab its name?

```
// worker.js
const oninit = options => {
  console.log(options.name); // ==> logs "myWorker"
};
```

I can't find such option... Am I getting the concept wrong or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess "init" happens when the worker is loaded / executed, so whatever you invoke directly in it runs immediately.
The `name` (`DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.name`) from the options should be readable as [`self.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope/name), so simply calling

```
// worker.js
console.log(self.name);
```

should do the trick (provided your worker's environment has working console).